# When I update from Android 10 to 11, I get "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-11

When I update from Android 10 to 11, I get "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)".
The procedure is as follows

1.Save files from targetSDK28 app to internal storage(This is a proprietary file.)

```
/storage/emulated/0/MyAppName/202109259092928414.hoge
```

2.Update your device from Android 10 to 11

3.Load the file created in step 1 from the app that has been updated to targetSDK30.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/storage/emulated/0/MyAppName/202109259092928414.hoge"))
```

> file.exists()=true
> file.canRead()=false

4.An error occurred.

> 09-16 12:16:40.582 27825 27825 W System.err:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /storage/emulated/0/MyAppName/202109259092928414.hoge: open failed:
> EACCES (Permission denied) 09-16 12:16:40.583 27825 27825 W
> System.err:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492) 09-16
> 12:16:40.583 27825 27825 W System.err:    at
> java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:160)

I have added and allowed storage permission in Manifest file and also on runtime for reading a file. However there is no Internal Storage Permission request available.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and also for Android 10 I was using this attribute also

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

This does not occur on devices that have not been updated with the OS.

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" is deprecated for android 11(targetSDK 30). You need to update code to scope storage to get access to storage for android 11 and above. [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: `However there is no Internal Storage Permission request available.` Your file is on external srorage.

Comment: But... What is the question? As what you are reporting does not come as a surprise. Google advised you to move your files before updating.

Comment: `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true` Your app should keep that in order to run on Android 10 deviced.

Comment: If you want access to the file request for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or let user choose file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: `When I update from Android 10 to 11, ` I read it that you are updating your app.

Comment: What I want to do is to move the files created by the targetSDK28 app to the in-app area after updating to the targetSDK30 app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.